# Using Python's beautiful soup to get only the titles of links of webpage

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new at this but Ive created a code to webscrape a list of links on a webpage.

here is the code that I have

```
page_to_scrape=requests.get('http://lungtung.com/nhacvang/pub/tapesbyletr.asp?strLTR=T&page=15')

soup=BeautifulSoup(page_to_scrape.text,"html.parser")
title=soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "subsection"})



for x in zip(title):
    print(x)

x.get_text()
```

the results that it gives me is

```
(<div class="subsection"><a href="tapes_d.asp?FrTapeID=819">Trường Sơn (đĩa nhựa): TS-000168-1</a></div>,)
(<div class="subsection"><a href="tapes_d.asp?FrTapeID=39">Trường Sơn 1: Hát Giữa Quê Hương</a></div>,)
(<div class="subsection"><a href="tapes_d.asp?FrTapeID=40">Trường Sơn 2: Quê Hương và Tuổi Trẻ</a></div>,)
(<div class="subsection"><a href="tapes_d.asp?FrTapeID=41">Trường Sơn 3: Quê Hương và Người Tình</a></div>,)
(<div class="subsection"><a href="tapes_d.asp?FrTapeID=42">Trường Sơn 4: Hôm Nay, Ngày Mai</a></div>,)
(<div class="subsection"><a href="tapes_d.asp?FrTapeID=43">Trường Sơn 5: Tình Trong Khói Lửa</a></div>,)
(<div class="subsection"><a href="tapes_d.asp?FrTapeID=44">Trường Sơn 6: Quê Hương và Tuổi Loạn</a></div>,)
(<div class="subsection"><a href="tapes_d.asp?FrTapeID=45">Trường Sơn 7: Quê Hương, Mùa Trăng, Mùa Thu</a></div>,)
(<div class="subsection"><a href="tapes_d.asp?FrTapeID=46">Trường Sơn 8: Băng Nhạc Trường Sơn</a></div>,)
(<div class="subsection"><a href="tapes_d.asp?FrTapeID=175">Trần Ngọc Đức: Băng Vàng - Bóng Tình Yêu</a></div>,)
```

this makes me happy because i know im getting somewhere, but I want it to print out is the only the names of the links towards the end (truong son 1, truong son 2, etc)
how would i go about that? i feel like i have to use a different function in the beautifulsoup library. but i dont know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use select for using with selectors. The names is in div.subsection and in this code I appended all to one list. Actually you can convert this list to dataframe or something.

```
page_to_scrape=requests.get('http://lungtung.com/nhacvang/pub/tapesbyletr.asp?strLTR=T&page=15')

soup=BeautifulSoup(page_to_scrape.text,"html.parser")
title=soup.select('div.subsection')


data = []
for x in title:
    data.append(x.text)

print(data)
```

I do not know why are you scraping just one page but you can scrape all pages like that.

```
data = []
for i in range(1,16):
    page_to_scrape = requests.get(f'http://lungtung.com/nhacvang/pub/tapesbyletr.asp?strLTR=T&page={i}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_to_scrape.text, "html.parser")
    title = soup.select('div.subsection')
    for x in title:
        data.append(x.text)



print(data)
```